400 Bad Request error when verifying challenge response with Google's Verified Access API
I am using the following code to send a challenge response to Google's Verify API for verification. However, I am encountering an error:
Verification Failed: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

code:
package org.example;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    private static final String VERIFIED_ACCESS_URL = "https://verifiedaccess.googleapis.com/v2/challenge:verify";
    // Fetch sensitive data from environment variables
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY = System.getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY"); 
    private static final String CHALLENGE_RESPONSE = System.getenv("CHALLENGE_RESPONSE");
    private static final String EXPECTED_IDENTITY = "KIOSK_MODE"; // Optional, set if needed

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Validate the challenge response
            String sanitizedResponse = CHALLENGE_RESPONSE.trim();
            if (!isValidBase64(sanitizedResponse)) {
                System.err.println("Invalid Base64 encoding in challenge response.");
                return;
            }

            String accessToken = getAccessToken();

            // Prepare the payload
            JSONObject payloadJson = new JSONObject();
            payloadJson.put("challengeResponse", sanitizedResponse);
            if (!EXPECTED_IDENTITY.isEmpty()) {
                payloadJson.put("expectedIdentity", EXPECTED_IDENTITY);
            }

            String payload = payloadJson.toString();
            System.out.println("Payload: " + payload);

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(payload, MediaType.parse("application/json"));

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(VERIFIED_ACCESS_URL)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            // Execute the request
            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                String responseBody = response.body() != null ? response.body().string() : "No response body";
                System.out.println("HTTP Response Code: " + response.code());
                System.out.println("Response Body: " + responseBody);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Verification Successful!");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Verification Failed. Reason: " + responseBody);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.getBytes()))
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/verifiedaccess"));
        credentials.refreshIfExpired();
        AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
        if (token == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to fetch the access token.");
        }
        return token.getTokenValue();
    }

    private static boolean isValidBase64(String input) {
        try {
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

I followed the Google Verified Access Documentation : https://developers.google.com/chrome/verified-access/developer-guide
1.The CHALLENGE_RESPONSE looks correct and is Base64-encoded.
2.The service account key and other configurations seem valid.
3.Payload being sent is in the correct JSON format.
What could be causing the INVALID_ARGUMENT error? Any suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
